# EF Core 2.0 Model does not get created

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am running `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=XXX;Database=XXX;User id=XXX;password=XXX"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir XXX` and no model is getting created. I have previously run this script on this computer, project, and database and the model has been created.

The packages that I have installed are :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.0.1),  
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.0.1), and  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (2.0.1)
```

If I run this script on a different computer but in the same project and database it runs and completes building the model for the database.

When I run this command with `-verbose` it returns:

```
Using project 'XXX'.  
Using startup project 'XXX'.  
Build started...  
Build succeeded.
```

Is there a reason that this would stop working?

Comment: Is there any difference if you drop the output dir before scaffolding?

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I got the same result after trying that.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of my version of Visual Studio 17. When I upgraded to version 15.4.4 the ef models stopped being created. I had to add `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` to my `<PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>` in my .csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```